# TypeScript - obtaining generic type information after a type has been erased

Tags: typescript

Since TypeScript uses type erasure for generics, I'm working on an alternative solution for gathering type information at runtime.

The solution I've come up with is similar to that in Java, using a `Class<T>`.

It works, but it doesn't feel...*complete*

```
type Class<T> = { prototype: T }

function passMeAClass<T>(cls: Class<T>): void {
    console.log(cls);
}

passMeAClass(String)
```

- Is `type Class<T> = { prototype: T }` *complete* enough?
- Is there a better approach to do this?

Comment: What are you going to do with a `Class<T>` value?  The sense in which an approach is "complete" or "better" really depends on your use cases.

Comment: @jcalz if, hypothetically speaking I was writing library code, then the question is "what is everyone else going to do with `Class<T>`?" and that opens this up to a whole lot of use cases. I'm trying to get into the mindset of _what would Microsoft do?_

Comment: Hmm, TypeScript uses erasure for the entire static type system, not just generics.  Since you're the one with the idea for `Class<T>` in the first place, I really don't know what you expect other people to do with it.  Microsoft has already [declined](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/20256) the idea of adding something like this to its standard libraries, so the answer to "what would Microsoft do" might not be helpful here.  As of now this question seems to be [opinion-based](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) unless you can explain more about why you need it.  ‍♂️

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to accomplish this usually is to use a constructor signature (similar with a function signature but with `new` in front of it):

```
type Constructor<T> = new (... args: any[]) => T;

function passMeAClass<T>(cls: Constructor<T>): void {
    console.log(cls);
}
passMeAClass(String)
```

This has the advantage of also being able to new up objects in the function. (so `new cls()` works for example).

Also for mixin scenarios you can use `cls` as a base type (your version would not work):

```
function extendTheClass<T extends Constructor<{}>>(cls: T) {
    return  class X extends cls {

    };
}
```

Comment: I did already think of this as an alternative solution, but what about things that have a prototype but not a constructor, like `Window`?

Comment: @series0ne Works for `Window` (it has a constructor) but it is true it will not work if there is no `public` constructor